# MySql case statement performance

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have an `UPDATE` I use pretty often (20-40 times/min).
Which should provide better results:

multiple calls with bind variables:
`Update Table set colA = :val1 where id = :val2`

or using a case statement with a variable number of values. (20-40...)

```
Update Table 
   set colA = (case when id = 1 then 'a' when id=2 then 'b'
```

The update is based on a primary key, meaning 1 row per id.

I'm using `MySQL` with `hibernate`.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, I would expect the query using bind parameters would perform better because the DML execution plan should be cached and re-used more easily rather than the case equivalent.